# Timestamp accuracy - gained milliseconds

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

If I store a `System.DateTime` as a timestamp in SQL using this fluent nhibernate mapping:

```
Map(x => x.LoggedTimeStamp).CustomType("Timestamp")
                           .Not.Nullable();
```

When I store and recall the timestamp:

```
new DateTime(2013, 5, 10, 14, 59, 13, 235);
```

It comes back equal to `new DateTime(2013, 5, 10, 14, 59, 13, 237)`;

It has gained 2 milliseconds. This is also evident in the SQL Server management studio.

My question is, can I tell NHibernate to use a more accurate field type?

Comment: There is a `datetime2` type in SQL Server that supports milliseond values that don't end in 0, 3 or 7, but I'm not sure whether it can be mapped by NHibernate. Lots of results returned when googling for NHibernate, fluent and datetime2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a limitation of SQL-Server's standard [datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) type.

> Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

Only in SQL Server <s>2012</s> 2008 and above are there more accurate datetime types. I don't know if you can make NHibernate use those (it would certainly destroy portability).

Alternatively, if this precision is really so important, you might save the datetime values as numbers or even strings, doing the conversion in NHibernate type convertors. I did something like it once (someone was using MySQL's 0000-00-00 date), but it was a long time ago and I don't know if the approach is still valid. Read NHibernate's documentation about custom data types.

Comment: I think `datetime2` was introduced in 2008, not the 2012 version. Bit difficult to prove since MSDN now only seems to server up 2012 and 2005 BOL.

Comment: SQL 2008 does have `datetime2` datatype.

Comment: Padon, I was looking at MSDN and made a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

`Datetime` datatype in SQL Serve stores data with precision of 3ms: the value stored may be +/- 3 ms.

Use `datetime2` datatype. it has precision of  100 nanoseconds.

Also `time` and `datetimeoffset` datatypes have precision of 100 nanoseconds in SQL 2008 and onwards.